# recursive function C program

Tags: c

`x` and `y` are integers, the function f(x, y) = x<sup>y</sup> needs to be calculated. Calculate the function `f(x, y)` recursively.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int f(int x, int y) {
    if (x == 0 && y != 0) {
        printf("answer: 0\n");
        return 0;
    } else if (x != 0 && y == 0) {
        printf("result: 1\n");
        return 1;
    } else if (x > 0 && y == 1) {
        f(x, 1) == x;
        return x;
    } else if (x > 0 && y > 0) {
        printf("result: %d\n", x * f(x, y - 1));
        return x * f(x, y - 1);
    } else {
        y = -y;
        printf("result: %d\n", 1 / f(x, y));
        return  1 / f(x, y);
    }
}
int main() {
    int k, l;
    float result;

    printf("*****************ust alma*********************\n\n");
    printf("enter two number: ");
    scanf("%d\n%d", &k, &l);
    result = f(k, l);
    printf("girilen result: %d", result);

    return 0;
}
```

I am waiting for your help I can not do this lesson.
Really hard for me.

Comment: I need calculate the function f (x, y) recursively., the codes are just examples but not working

Comment: What do you expect of this kind of test `x>0 && x<0` ?

Comment: `f(x,1)==x;` just discards the result of the function call and comparison - what were you intending to do here?

Comment: I have tried to reindent your code, return is missing for some else, some tests are always false. `%d` and result are not consistent. What is the definition on `f` ?

Comment: ohh sorry I'm fixing

Comment: @has What is your function f is supposed to do exactly are you trying to raise x to the power of y ?

Comment: Your `if(x==0 && y==0)` has no `return` so it "falls through" to the function end where there is no `return`.  Compile with `-Wall -O2` [which you should _always_ do] and this would be flagged. _Side note:_ Convention/style guides [almost universally] say do `if (...)` and _not_ `if(...)`. That is reserved [usually used] for function calls.

Comment: (x) (y) is just `x*y`, in other words the answer should be `return x*y;`. You should force use of recursion where the problem doesn't call for it.

Comment: @bobobobo I think he is trying to raise x to y

Comment: My English little, i can't understand some words sorry..

Comment: Use `<sup>superscript</sup>` for exponents (x<sup>y</sup> if that's what you intend). The other way programmers sometimes show exponentiation is `x^y`

Comment: Sorry,  [`<sup>` stopped working](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296134/sup-superscript-html-tag-has-ceased-to-work-correctly)

Comment: @has what are you doing here `else if(x>0 && x<0 && y>0)` ? this is never going to be TRUE

Comment: I fixed it right now

Comment: x<sup>y</sup> doesn't seem to render properly!

Comment: Think about how you might write it as a loop.  What would happen for each iteration of the loop?  The loop iteration will be your recursive function call.   The loop counter is going to be one of the arguments.  The recursive function will need an exit condition.  It should return the value that it calculates.  Give it another try with these points in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some issue on your type, with negative y your need to use `double` or `float`. 
You will get 0 with `int`
I have simplified your function, you were closed

Not the `.` for 1 to use a double and not an `int`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


double f(int x, int y){
    if(y == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else if(y > 0) {
        return x * f(x, y - 1);
    } else {
        y = -y;
        return  1. / f(x, y);
    }
}
int main() {
    int k,l;
    float result;

    printf("*****************ust alma*********************\n\n");
    printf("enter two number: ");
    scanf("%d\n%d", &k, &l);
    result = f(k,l);
    printf("girilen result: %f\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank u very much!

Comment: 0,0 should return 1 actually

Comment: @nikoss: Thank you for this gem. Learn something new everyday :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>

double my_pow(ssize_t x,ssize_t y)
{
    if (y==0)return 1.0;
    else if (y==1)return x;
    else if (y<0) return 1.0/my_pow(x,-y);
    else return x*my_pow(x,--y);
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%.2lf\n",my_pow(2,-1));
}
```

Comment: The `l` in `%.2lf` is redundant and ignored. `ssize_t` is a non standard type.

Comment: isnt ssize_t posix standard ?

Comment: `ssize_t` is defined in POSIX, but not in the C Standard. Why use `ssize_t`  instead of `int` or `long`?

Comment: because ssize_t is exactly a word size of the target machine but int or long might have alignment issues. I am writing rust normally and in rust we throw isize and usize everywhere possible so this is somewhat c equivalent of it @chqrlieforyellowblockquotes

Comment: I understand your concern, but it is largely irrelevant in this context (IMHO).

Comment: why is .2lf redundant ?

Comment: Because, unlike `scanf`'s, the `printf` conversion specifier for a `double` argument is `%f`, not `%lf`. `float` arguments are automatically converted to `double` when passed as extra arguments to vararg functions, so there is no need to distinguish `float` and `double` arguments.

Comment: thanks for the info it is kinda hard to get a proper documentation about c features

Comment: I suggest you download a copy of http://www2.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf and monitor this page for up to date standards info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents

Comment: @chqrlieforyellowblockquotes that is awesome thanks. Can you also suggest anything on cross compilation, linking and stuff? I am having really hard time trying to compile openssl for musl to use in rust for a week already to no avail.

Comment: If you run into issues with the musl libc, you can ask specific questions here, Rich Felker, the author, is quite active on SO as @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a compact solution:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

double f(int x, int y) {
    return y ? y < 0 ? f(x, y + 1) / x : f(x, y - 1) * x : 1;
}

int main() {
    int x, y;
    printf("*****************ust alma*********************\n\n"
           "enter two numbers: ");
    if (scanf("%d%d", &x, &y) == 2)
        printf("girilen result: %f\n", f(x, y));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

double f(int x, int y)
{
    return y<0 ? 1 / f(x, -y)  :
           y   ? x * f(x, y-1) : 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%.3f\n", f(4,0));  // To the 0-power: 1
    printf("%.3f\n", f(4,1));  // To the 1-power: X
    printf("%.3f\n", f(4,-2)); // To the negative power: 1/(X^Y)
    return 0;
}
```

## Output

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 4472KB
1.0000
4.0000
0.0625
```